# How to link customized bootstrap into index.html file?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, customization

I am new to bootstrap (just started learning) and I have recently customized my bootstrap file on http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/

i compiled and downloaded and then i find it hard to link it with my index.html file. Source of bootstrap files is on local drive and in my code it looks like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="desc">
    <meta name="keywords" content="content">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">    

    <title>TITLE</title>
  </head>
  <body>    

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->     
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"/> 
  </body>
</html>
```

pls help :)

Comment: What do you mean by hard to link? Your custom stylesheet will go below bootstrap in your `head`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new to Bootstrap, the first thing you should do is use the latest version (ie. Bootstrap 4.0).

A good way to kickstart your project is to use CDN, Bootstrap files are hosted in remote server so you don't have to manage Bootstrap files locally. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/#bootstrapcdn

Check the console in your browser to be sure everything is correctly loaded.

To include your custom css, just put in head your css like you would do with any html page.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom_main.css">
</head>
```